# How can I modify my following Pig Latin script to perform Set Intersection efficiently

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to Pig and am trying to run the following PigScript on our 5-node hadoop cluster. The following script gives me the set intersection of two columns in a relation

```
register '/home/workspace/Pig/setIntersecUdf.jar'; 
define Inter com.cs.pig.SetIntersection(); 
a = load '/home/pig/pig-0.12.0/input/location.txt' as (location:chararray); 
b = load '/home/pig/pig-0.12.0/input/location.txt' as (location:chararray); 
c = CROSS a,b parallel 10; 
c = DISTINCT c; 
d = Foreach c generate $0,$1,Inter($0,$1) as intersection; 
e = Filter d by intersection !='[]' parallel 10; 
e = Filter e by $0!=$1 parallel 10; 
Store e into '/home/Documents/Pig_output';
```

I have a 6 Mb file which contains Locations like san diego CA or san d CA. I want the third column to be an intersection of both i.e. [san, CA]. I have this file with 321,372 records and have to take a CROSS of this with itself to get two columns so that I can process each tuple at a time.

As, pointed out to me,t his 6 Mb file translates to around 1.9 Tb and hence, my job fails because of insufficient disk space.

What changes can I make to this script to make it run efficiently?

Following is the error I am getting:

```
Java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/temp-10926921/tmp-1823693600/_temporary/_attempt_201401171541_0001_r_000000_0/part-r-00000 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639) 
at  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:469)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:432)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:404)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:256)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:650)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/temp-10926921/tmp-1823693600/_temporary/_attempt_201401171541_0001_r_000000_0/part-r-00000 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
at $Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
at $Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3686)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3546)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2749)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2989)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't understand what you're trying to intersect.  Can you give a small sample input and desired output?

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus From the example, it seems like he wants to compare all lines of the file against each other, and return the common tokens from each comparison.

Comment: Can you clarify how com.cs.pig.SetIntersection works?  Does it tokenize each string to produce two sets of words and then intersects these two?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `DISTINCT` after the `CROSS` is very unlikely to do anything. `DISTINCT` respects order, so it will only get rid of tuples that are exactly the same.  This should only be the case if you have multiples of the same line in the input file.

The `e = Filter e by $0!=$1`... should be done before you find the intersections for the lines.  You are going to throw them out anyways, so you are going to want to do that as soon as possible.

To solve this, you are going to need to limit the `CROSS` somehow.  I don't know what your data looks like, or what you are expecting as output, but `GROUP`ing the data by state beforehand should cut down on the number of tuples `CROSS` will make dramatically.  However, this will not return the intersection for things like: `foo CA` and `foo CT`.

Answer (score 0):

CROSSing relations results in a big increase in data volume, even in orders of magnitude.
Often there is a more efficient solution, that is dependent on the data itself. If you could add a few records from each set and explain what the desired output should contain, the community would be able to assist you.